# How can I use a package as a jar in the project

Tags: java, jar

my project is huge. Taking a certain package in the project and transforming it into jars. How can I use it again in the project. 
I get some errors when I add the package I converted to jar as external library. 
When I added my tcallable statement class as an external library, my classes using the methods in it got an error.

```
tc.setString (1, message);
tc.setString (2, mailTo);
tc.setString (3, subject);
tc.setString (4, "DEFAULT EMAIL CLIENT");
tc.execut A ();
```

how can i solve this.

Comment: If the project contains `module-info` then it would be piece of cake otherwise you will be stuck for a while. It's a good point to start, learn about it.

Comment: My project is not contains  module-info. Why does it force me can you explain that a little bit?